# Image wont load in from camera on newer Android phones

Tags: android, camera

I am using a java based code to open the phone camera, take a photo and then return the file path to load the image into the app.  It works fine on older Android versions but on new Android version the camera DOES open, but after taking the photo nothing happens and the photo is not loaded in.

Here is the code:

```
try
{
Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File photo = new File(path, Name);
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
//RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity.startActivity(i);
RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity.startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);

return 1;
}
catch (SecurityException e)
{
return -1.0;
}
```

and:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// Check which request we're responding to
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
// Make sure the request was successful     
int dsMapIndex = RunnerJNILib.jCreateDsMap(null, null, null);
RunnerJNILib.DsMapAddString( dsMapIndex,"type","Camera" );
RunnerJNILib.DsMapAddString( dsMapIndex,"os","Android" );
RunnerJNILib.CreateAsynEventWithDSMap(dsMapIndex, EVENT_OTHER_SOCIAL);          
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think this could be the exact problem but startActivityForResult() is deprecated and I strongly recommend you to implement the new way: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Answer (score 0):

> > Uri.fromFile(photo))

Do not use Uri.fromFile() but use FileProvider to build up a content scheme uri to serve your file.

Comment: What I found after trying various different modifications is that on newer android devices the photo was not being saved, so it didnt exist when we tried to import it.  

So i changed the target path of the new photo to:

    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)

This replaced the previous:

    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

Now it seems to work, but ive not tested this with older devices.